# How to load a PDF before it's view is pushed

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I'd like to load the PDF in my child view before it gets pushed onto the navigation stack. Right now there is a brief delay while the UIWebview is loading up the PDF file. What I would like is the PDF to be loaded so it slides on to the screen with the view.

I tried customizing the initWithNib method like below but then nothing loads. My thought was "If I start the PDF load during initialization it'll be ready when I go to push it." Guess not.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:pdfURL ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
 }
return self;
```

}

Here's my current implementation:

In the parent view I initialize the pdfViewer using this:

```
            PDFViewerVC *vc = [[PDFViewerVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"PDFViewerVC" bundle:nil];
        vc.pdfURL = @"Service Manual RS20";
        vc.title = [self.list objectAtIndex:row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc release];
```

In the pdfViewer I load the PDF using this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:pdfURL ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get very far with UIWebView, you need to go deeper, use Quartz.
Of course that means you need to replicate much that UIWebView has.

Check Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer for a simple example. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the UIWebView's [`webViewDidFinishLoad:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) delegate method is called before pushing its view controller onto the navigation stack.